# Pyomo doesn't receive solution from solver

Tags: python, package, cplex, pyomo

I run `pyomo` with `cplex` for a while now. I code in Jupyter. Today I pip installed 'nteract', an extension for Jupyter. Since then I have this problem: My `pyomo` models don't get solved anymore. Pandas and Pyomo packages weren't found anymore. So I pip installed them again. Since then it doesn't work right anymore:

When I execute:

```
In [13]: solver = SolverFactory('cplex')
         print(solver.solve(model))
```

I receive from the solver:

```
Problem:
- Lower bound: -inf
  Upper bound: inf
  Number of objectives: 1
  Number of constraints: 0
  Number of variables: None
  Number of nonzeros: None
  Sense: unknown
Solver:
- Status: ok
  Termination condition: unknown
  Error rc: 0
  Time: 0.04337573051452637
```

...even though my model is constructed and contains all the variables, constraints, etc.

It does it for different models too.
[Here(PDF)](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1SmbrXw9vMcVIf5lrOvHQnn3EWYReA2GM) is my example if you want to see it.

But I think it has something to do with the environment I run all this in and I don't have any ideas on how to tackle this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

problem discovered by solving the model with `tee=Tree`.

problem solved: One shouldn't have blank spaces in the path to python file. Blank spaces in python file itself don't make this error occur.

Issue reported [on GitHub](https://github.com/Pyomo/pyomo/issues/480).

Edit: Issue fixed and closed.